# Семантика: количество уменьшилось / количество снизилось

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, семантика

Какое из словосочетаний семантически некорректно и почему?

- количество (тестов) уменьшилось
- количество (тестов) снизилось

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Некорректно сочетание  количество (тестов) **снизилось.**

Количество - категория, характеризующая предметы со стороны величины, числа. Оно может быть больше или меньше, уменьшиться или увеличиться. Повыситься или снизиться количество не может.

Снизиться - стать ниже, более низким (по цене, норме, положению, уровню и т.д.).